# npm install cannot install dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have deleted node modules and my package.json file
I run the command `npm install` 
But a certain dependency is stopping it from installing.
It gives the following error

```
freduah@freduah:~/react-ebay-clone/react-ebay-clone$ npm install
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (sha512-qruRsoEuFvaVsSSlhNtHR8uWgF7aA6jdRtCuVKO4pMW32lTZfGS+U/y6hB0YBxXv4xhEn8o1x/15oLU7cNUxEA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (sha512-yGdq06wUxreCPxXnhqlL3GzvLtArJ6eDOQinv4SiDK+ftQPY4TloEMQr/rwohvtx63O+bT9jAtgJW44jlfIQ2Q==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (sha512-qruRsoEuFvaVsSSlhNtHR8uWgF7aA6jdRtCuVKO4pMW32lTZfGS+U/y6hB0YBxXv4xhEn8o1x/15oLU7cNUxEA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (sha512-Pva9ZNjUieD2/RVav7LYGAXZ1O6MVXlvOnJmHSmjP4rhreek7/Ez7b5HsCEN3YLjZIcPHH8SV8Duix1NO2zB5A==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

It has been running for almost an hour now.
I have quit and rerun the operation for several times now yet it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I haven't faced any problems like the above with npm, but I did some google searches and found some solutions.

1. You can try to clear [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#random-errors) if you haven't tried.
2. You can try something like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14971#issuecomment-508235202), but the same error with the angular module.
3. You can try to delete the package-lock.json file and try `npm install` [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/1445745/getting-weird-error-when-doing-npm-install-in-my-angular-project)
4. Or if the above doesn't work then, you can reinstall NodeJS, this might help.